# Measure to capture clustering in time based event

Tags: methodology

I am searching for a good measure to capture clustering in time based events. Say that for a given interval of 5 minutes, cars randomly pass in front of house ... say one car at every 10 seconds (for a total of 30 cars). For another interval of 5 minutes, 3 cars passes at every thirty seconds, and the time between the three cars is 0 (again 30 cars over 5 minutes). The difference between both intervals is that for the second intervals, the arrival of cars "clusters". What can be a good measure to capture clustering? I would like a measure that indicates that there was more clustering in the second interval than the first one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the measure you are looking for is called "clumpiness," or non-constant propensity, or rather temporary elevations of propensity, characterized by serial dependence and non-stationarity. Take a look at the draft version of [New Measures of Clumpiness for Incidence Data by Yao Zhang, Eric Bradlow, and Dylan Small](http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~dsmall/clumpiness_paper.pdf) for some alternative ways to measure this sort of thing. The paper starts out defining some desirable properties of clumpiness measures:

- Minimum - the measure should be at the minimum if the events are equally spaced
- Maximum - the measure should be at the maximum if all the events are gathered together
- Continuity - shifting event timing by a very small amount should only change the measure by a small amount
- Convergence - as events move closer/further apart, the measure should increase/decrease

Then it evaluates several existing measures and proposes 4 new ones. It also evaluates them using some simulation with various types of DGPs. There's also an empirical illustration using Hulu data.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! sorry for the late reply! I will check the paper

Comment: in fact the measure I had in mind was a simple D'agostino Ksquare but that would only work if I assume that my theoretical dist. is normal...though I want to assume uniform.

Answer (score 0):

If the cars pass following a Poisson distribution of 6 cars per minute, the time between cars is exponential rate 1/6 of a minute. Compare both examples to the exponential distribution using the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test. The clustered one will be significantly different (provided you have enough data). The regularly spaced one should also be significantly different as it isn't random, though I don't expect you mean the cars pass precisely every ten seconds.

Comment: thanks! Yes I assume that the regularly spaced one is more random than cars that pass precisely at every ten seconds. I will take a look at the KS test.

Comment: but can I use the KS to assign a value or number to each intervals for their "degree" of clustering? I believe that they KS test is simply use for hypothetical testing. - I would like to do a cross-sectional comparison. And that value of clustering that I assign to each interval, I will use it in cross-sectional regression.