# How to statistically make inferences about how close are repeated events to each other?

Tags: r, repeated-measures, survival, stata, recurrent-events

I have data about patient hospital readmission within one year after surgery. About two thirds of patients were readmitted, and the number of readmissions for those readmitted vary from 1 to 8 times. In addition, I have data about the dates of these readmissions and their duration, so I can calculate the duration between any two readmissions for all patients. My question is, how could I test whether these readmissions are close together or are scattered throughout the year and not closely related? Closely related readmissions are likely more preventable through improved care coordination, quality of care delivered, etc.

Comment: This might be a relevant [thread](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/46129/7071).

Comment: Dear Dimitriy, thanks very much for sharing. This is exactly what I was looking for!